# How to subtract a number of workdays from a date in excel

Tags: excel, date

I currently have a date coded as mm/cc/yyyy in a cell. In another cell, I would like to subtract a certain number (for the sake of this example let's say 5) WORKING days.

If, for example, the date was May 16, 2012, then the result would yield May 9, 2012.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: A minor point but perhaps worth noting. "m/d/yyyy" is a display format. Excel holds dates as the number of days since 31-Dec-1899. Type 41045 is a cell, format it as a date and it will be displayed as 16-May-2012. Time is held as a fraction: (Number of seconds since midnight) / (Number of seconds in a day).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this page, [Date Arithmetic](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datearith.htm)--specifically the section Subtracting Dates. Note the WORKDAY function in the last paragraph.

For example, if the source date is in A2 and the days prior (as a nonnegative value) is in B2:

```
=TEXT(WORKDAY(A2, B2 * -1), "m/d/yyyy")
```

Comment: I found workday function somewhere else but it didnt made much sense till I saw your text function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [NETWORKDAYS()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) function, which is available in the Analysis ToolPak add-in.

You might find that [WORKDAY()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/WORKDAY-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33) suffices.